# Is there an API to access a Google Group data?

Tags: python, google-groups

I'm trying to build some statistics for an email group I participate. Is there any Python API to access the email data on a GoogleGroup?

Also, I know some statistics are available on the group's main page. I'm looking for something more complex than what is shown there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an API that I know of, however you can access the XML feed and manipulate it as required.

Comment: Does the XML feed has all messages on the whole history of the group?

Comment: No Rodrigo, as far as I know the only RSS feeds you can access are:

15 New Messages
50 New Messages
15 New Topics
50 New Topics

Comment: @Bane Yes, just checked and it is like you said. I'm impressed Google didn't provide an API to access that data...